# BS4 giving a weird a random output from scraping a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The website I am trying to scrape is https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/gamerboy80#BedWars. This website contains two `<table class="table">` that I am trying to scrape.
**My Code**

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "gamerboy80"
mode = "BedWars"

# Soup
r = requests.get(f'https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/{username}#{mode}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


data = [[cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')[1:4]]
        for row in soup.find_all(class_="table")][1]
print(data)
```

I added `[1]` after declaring the `data` variable to call the second element in HTML. What I am getting is

> ['Kills', 'Basic', '221']

What I want is:

> ['5,437', '4,671', '1.16']

On the site, these are named Kills, Deaths, and K/D. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Looks like the data is loaded via javascript so you'll need to either determine the AJAX call that gets the data and duplicate that using requests or use something that runs javascript such as Selenium. If you save `r.content` into a file then inspect the file, you'd see that the data you want is not there. Or the data may be in some `<script>...</script>` tag; cannot be bothered to check at the moment. Try browsing the page with javascript off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other `<table>` tags on the website, so doing `soup.find_all(class_="table")][1]` would select the wrong table.

Instead, you can select the table using:

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "gamerboy80"
mode = "BedWars"

# Soup
r = requests.get(f"https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/{username}#{mode}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")


data = [
    tag.text for tag in soup.select_one("#collapse-1-2 > div > table").select("td")[:3]
]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['5,437', '4,671', '1.16']
```